# How to autoload class files of paypal php sdk in zend framework 2?

Tags: php, paypal, zend-framework2

I am using paypal sdk classes in my controllers like below :

```
$apiContext = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
            new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
            'AYSq3RDGsmBLJE-otTkBtM-jBRd1TCQwFf9RGfwddNXWz0uFU9ztymylOhRS', // ClientID
            'EGnHDxD_qRPdaLdZz8iCr8N7_MzF-YHPTkjs6NKYQvQSBngp4PTTVWkPZRbL'      // ClientSecret
            )
    );
    var_dump($apiContext); die;
```

But the above code giving me error like :

```
Fatal error: Class 'PayPal\Rest\ApiContext' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin.ikeydelivery.com\module\Dashboard\src\Dashboard\Controller\OrderController.php on line 49
```

So tell me how I autoload these classes in zendframework2.

Comment: you have to use the namespace at the top in order to use that class it looks like class ApiContext is missing

Comment: I can use the class with namespace without putting the use keyword in the top

Comment: As you can see controller is unable to find the class PayPal\Rest\ApiContext so, to fix it you have to use the namespace of that class in your controller .... also can you post your controller namespace and use classes

Comment: Hello bro,
If I am not using the namespace in the top than a alternate option is when we create instance of any class that time we put the namespace with the class what I have done above. 
The issue is not with the namespace the issue is with the autoload file of paypal sdk. where I put that file so all the classes of sdk are available in the application.

Comment: Did you install the Paypal library using Composer?

Comment: Try to download it using composer

Answer (score 4):

You just run composer like that:

```
composer require "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php:*"
```

and it will do all the autoloading for you.

Answer (score -2):

If the PayPal SDK has a classloader file, just add it to the getAutoloaderConfig function of Module.php.

```
public function getAutoloaderConfig() {
    return array(
        'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/paypalsdk/classloader.php',
        ),
    );
}
```

If that doesn't work, you can always create a new file autoload_classmap.php and add each php class from the PayPal SDK:

```
return array(
    'PayPal\Rest\ApiContext'         => __DIR__ . '/paypalsdk/ApiContext.php',
);
```

and add it to the AutoloaderConfig:

```
public function getAutoloaderConfig() {
    return array(
        'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
        ),
    );
}
```